# WebView not loaded to the edge of the phone or status bar. Especially in iPhoneX

Tags: ios, webview, autolayout, uinavigationbar

I have 2 VC, one main and another detail. They are embedded in a `Navigation Controller`. At my main VC, I have set my `webview` for Top, Bottom, Trailing and Leading all to the superview. When the VC is loaded, the webview will properly align all the way to top just before the status bar. All the phones aligned properly and loaded properly. [image: Pic 1]

When I go into my detail page, I will have my `back navigation controller`. I still want to load my `webview` for the top part, all the way auto aligned to the edge of the phone or just before the status bar. Again, I set the top, bottom, trailing and leading edges all to superview. The webView loaded as [image: follow.]

But I want the webview to move further up and cover all the black area. Hence I change the top edge to superview to -60 [image: -60]

I managed to simulate the ipHone 8 and iPhone SE to load correctly but when comes to iPhoneX, it is not loaded correctly. It is not neither to the edge of phone nor to the edge of the status bar [image: not loaded correctly].

How do I play around with the constraint so I can load the webview either to the edge of the the phone or the status bar. Please help, thanks.

## I have set the following values.

[image]

But I still get this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

I realise that the height of the navigation bar is 44 points across all phones. I maintained my Top Space Equal to Superview but adjusted the constant to -44.